# How to custom Trailing metadata in gRPC Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, grpc

I'm using gRPC with Spring Boot application and want to send some custom Trailing metadata like execution time at server.

How can I do that?

I implemented a `ServerInterceptor` but don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/interop-testing/src/main/java/io/grpc/testing/integration/TestServiceImpl.java#L583 . Override `close()` in your `SimpleForwardingServerCall` to add your trailers.